# Is it possible to use a different data set as input for prediction in AdaBoostRegressor (sklearn)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, adaboost

I am just beginner of machine learning and I am playing sklearn now.
I copied the example of AdaBoostRegressor from official site at [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_adaboost_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-adaboost-regression-py) and added the following.

```
X_pred = np.linspace (6, 12, 100)[:, np.newaxis]
y_pred = regr_2.predict(X_1)
```

As the training data set X is ranged from 0 to 6, I am trying to get a prediction for a different data set X_pred ranged from 6 to 12.

However, I found that the value of y_pred is always -1.05382839 which is the last value of training set output y.
I am wondering whether it is possible to use a non-input-sample data set as the input of prediction.
Is it possible to do that? If so what is the correct usage?

BTW, attached pic is the output.
Red and green are the predicated output based on training set input (0-6) and blue is the output of X_pred (6 - 12).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In short - **no**. This is not what regression is about. Regression is about **interpolation**, not **extrapolation**. Pretty much none of the regressors can make any predictions about data **outside** of the training set.

Comment: Hi Lejlot, thank you for your explanation. So what should I look for if I want to do extrapolation?